# Double-nested loop with bitwise operation

Tags: time-complexity, imperative-programming, binary-arithmetic

I have this little exercise:

```
for ( i = 0; i < 2 * n; i += 2 )
  for ( j = 1; j <= n; j <<= 1 )
    if ( j & i )
      foo ();
```

(`j <<= 1` means `j = (j << 1)`, where `<<` is the bitwise left shift operator. `&` is the bitwise and operator.)

I am supposed to determine how many times will the *foo* function be called for some *n*. The result should be both an exact number (or the most accurate approximation possible) and asymptotic (like O(n)).

Comment: Suggestion: you could try compiling and running the code with a few different values of n, just to get a feel for how the answers should look.

Comment: It's analysis so I should use just pencil and paper.

Comment: Running the code is (a) instructive and (b) a useful reality-check against any theoretical answers that you come up with

Answer (score 4):

The number of `foo()` calls is the number of 1 bits in all numbers from 0 to $n$ (or all even numbers between $0$ and $2n$ - same thing). Asymptotically, it's $O(n \log n)$, because the number of 1 bits is around $\log_2(n)/2$.

I don't have an exact function. It won't be a smooth function - for example, $f(1023)-f(1022)=10$, but $f(1024)-f(1023)=1.$